# connected component extraction in openCv

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv

can anyone suggest a openCV method which extract connected components in a 8bit single  channel frame? is it cvBlobs suitable for this?
In addition to this i want to use it in C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [cvFindContours](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) function can help you.

Comment: @YilmazPaçariz I've never used cvBlobs library but from [official site](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/) I read that  it may also help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'll make answer cause I can not comment other answers.

I don't think so cvFindContours() extracts connected components well. For example from continuous Canny output, output from cvFindContours is segmented, I suppose that functions runs connected components, when there is point which more components can be connected it chooses some path to go. Component started from this point(not assigned to previous) is stored in different contour.

So the function cvFindContour is not good for connected component analysis. When I wanted to have non segmentated contours i have written my own function extracting them from canny output.

Blob extracting libs, based on OpenCV have connecting components functions. You can also write your own. There are lot of algorithms in pseudo code easy to implement.